# How can I efficiently check if a file exists in multiple subdirectories in perl?

Tags: performance, perl, mechanize

I have a single directory with 3 million small (~10k each in size) HTML files downloaded using WWW::Mechanize. This is not practical for obvious reasons. However, the reason why I have it this way is that my perl downloader script checks the directory to see if the file exists before downloading. If the file exists, the downloader skips to the next line. If not, download. I'm running around 10 download tasks simultaneously, each with a shuffled version of the download list, so checking is critical.

I am going to break the files up into around 300 subdirectories. I don't know exactly how many yet, because it will be broken up based on the first 3 letters of the filenames. So my question is what would be the most **efficient** way (and how) to write a search function in the perl downloader file that checks every subdirectory? I'd like to do this so it doesn't spend an insane amount of time checking.

This is what my search function looks like right now for checking if the file exists in the single directory. If anyone can help me update the function, I'd much appreciate it. I'm not really fluent in perl (my download script was already written, I just added the file check), which is why I'm asking.

```
######setup
my $file = "s5.txt";
open(my $fh, "<", "$file") or die "Unable to open < $file: $!";
my @lines = <$fh>;
my $counter = 0;
chomp(@lines);
close $fh;
my $size = @lines;

#####loop that's running
while( $counter < $size)  {   


########checker, part I need help with
my $filename = "/var/www/mydownloader/data/downloads/$lines[$counter].html";

if (-s $filename) {
print "the file exists. Skipping\n";
} else {
print "the file does not exist! Downloading! \n";

#....... download stuff

}
```

Comment: I would create a database (perhaps even SQLite) where you store the names of the files you've downloaded. Instead of searching the file system, just do a database query instead.

Comment: Why not simply use a directory name based on the file name, i.e. something like `substr($lines[$counter],0,3)`? Then it is again checking only a single location and not checking through lots of directories. If all the names are too similar and thus would end up in only few directories you could also use something like `substr(Digest::SHA::sha1_hex($lines[$counter],0,5))` as directory name. And to avoid a race don't check and then create but instead use `sysopen($fh,$name,O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_RDWR)` which fails if the file is already there.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich wow that's brilliant. Thank you for that, I would have never come up with something that simple.

Comment: @Programmer4Life: The idea is actually old. Many years ago when NNTP (Usenet) was a hot thing and file systems did not scale well with many directory entries, this was the way the messages were spread over 1000s of directories with multiple hierarchies for faster access to a specific message.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich well I would not have come up with that, so thank you? Do you have any tips on how to come up with simple solutions? It's a larger problem I have as a developer. I will come up with some complicated solution and miss the obvious answer in front of me.

Comment: @Programmer4Life: be curious what others do, read, and of course simply get experience :)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich trying to delete a local copy of the 3 million HTML file folder actually crashed my Mac, which is a new 2019 model. Wouldn't boot after that and I had to boot into single user mode and remove it from ~/.Trash so my Mac would boot. Windows didn't perform much better, Explorer froze when I accidentally clicked on the folder. I think it's safe to say that this use case still isn't handled well in OS's!

Comment: You are looking for a solution to a problem that you yourself are creating when you shuffle the download list. Partition the list sanely, even if it's just a `mod` rotation, and you no longer need to worry that another process already downloaded a file.

Comment: So once you break it up into 300 subdirs, each will have around 10K files ... what's wrong with `sysopen` then (as @SteffenUllrich showed you)? From what I remember system's handling of directories starts slowing down once there's hundreds of thousands of entries.  Besides, that's the only thing you can do, really; any file checks suffer from a race condition with concurrent downloads, whereby the "newer" file (in micro seconds) would _quietly_ overwrite the "older" one (more likely with `-s` then with `-e`)

Comment: Well it is not obvious why you do something like what you do. May be you need to look into [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) instead. Now about potential problems -- access is slow if number of files in a directory goes into thousands, you can have a problem with a command as `rm *` -- shell will attempt to expand `*` and will run out of **memory** allocated for _exansion of glob_, potentially you can run out of **inodes** on your _filesystem_ (very unlikely with normal use but your case is abnormal).